# error while inserting values in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

```
insert into ticket values<&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );
Enter value for t_no: 1
Enter value for b_date: 11
Enter value for fare: 100
Enter value for tr_date: 22
Enter value for cno:
old   1: insert into ticket values<&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno )
new   1: insert into ticket values<1,11 ,100 ,22 ,2 )
insert into ticket values<1,11 ,100 ,22 ,2)`
```

Comment: you have syntax error `<`

Comment: ERROR at line 1:``
ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: insert into ticket values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );

Comment: What's the `<` sign doing in the insert statement?

Comment: it is corrected but error still occur.

Comment: insert into ticket values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );

Comment: Try to put column names.

Comment: `insert into ticket(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );`

Comment: Means i don't understand?

Comment: ,20-11-11 ,2 )
insert into ticket(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) values(1,11-11-17 ,100 ,20-11-1
1 ,2 )
                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COL5": invalid identifier

Comment: col1, col2, ... is just an example.  Replace with your actual column names.

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: SQL> insert into ticket values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );
Enter value for t_no: 1
Enter value for b_date: 11/11/17
Enter value for fare: 111
Enter value for tr_date: 12/12/19
Enter value for cno: 2
old   1: insert into ticket values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno )
new   1: insert into ticket values(1,11/11/17 ,111 ,12/12/19 ,2 )
insert into ticket values(1,11/11/17 ,111 ,12/12/19 ,2 )

Comment: Learn here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php

Comment: please add schema of your table or Create table query

Comment: can you  please decribe

Comment: SQL> desc ticket;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------

 T_NO                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 B_DATE                                             DATE
 FARE                                               NUMBER(10)
 TR_DATE                                            DATE
 CNO                                                NUMBER(10)

Comment: SQL> insert into ticket values(&t_no,&b_date ,&fare ,&tr_date ,&cno );

Comment: Enter value for t_no: 1
Enter value for b_date: 24 jan 2018
Enter value for fare: 111
Enter value for tr_date: 28 jan 2018
Enter value for cno: 2

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma

Answer (score 0):

> `insert into ticket values(1,11/11/17 ,111 ,12/12/19 ,2 )`

Dates have to be input as strings and cast to date datatypes. So your code needs to be something like this:

```
insert into ticket values (&t_no, to_date('&b_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
                           ,&fare ,to_date('&tr_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ,&cno );
```

Note that I have made an assumption about your date format mask. If you're working with American style dates you'll need to change the masks accordingly.